# JasperReports Conditional Style in Javascript

Tags: jasper-reports

The Conditional Style examples posted online are written in Java language, for example the code below `new Boolean($V{some_variable} == 10)`.

Assuming that my report default language is Javascript, how to write the condition?

```
<style name="style1" forecolor="black">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression>
            <![CDATA[new Boolean($V{some_variable} == 10)]]>
        </conditionExpression>
        <style forecolor="green" isBold="true"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as removing the `Boolean` object instantiation:

```
<![CDATA[$V{some_variable} == 10]]>
```

Comment: I cannot compile the report when language is set to `javascript` (I'm building the report programmatically with JasperDesign class), I get `NoSuchMethodError: org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.enterContext()`. Are you sure this should work? By the way, I added Rhino library (optional dependency in JR) and still get the `NoSuchMethod` error.